# Not able to call SAVE method on Model object Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

I'm trying to call `save` method on an object of a Model `Complaints Model` to update a specific resource in Database but when I send a POST request on api url it gives this error

> BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.

I also tried calling `update` method but same error.

**Code for edit:**

```
$complaint = Complaint::where('complaint_id', $request->input('id'))->get();

            $complaint->title = $request->input('Complaint_Subject');
            $complaint->description = $request->input('Complaint_Details');
            $complaint->address = $request->input('Complaint_Address');

            $complaint->update();

            return [
                'save_status' => "success"
            ];
```

the very first line is returning the response and correct response.

**AND**

also I'm trying to call `delete` or `destroy` method to delete the resource but it also gives the same error

> BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::delete does not exist.

or

> BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::destroy does not exist.

**Code for delete:**

```
$complaint = Complaint::where('complaint_id', $request->input('id'))->get();
            $complaint->destroy($request->input('id'));

            return [
                'request_status' => 'success',
                'complaint' => $complaint
            ];
```

here also the response is being returned correctly.

Note that the **`complaint_id`** is not Primary Key in the table so I cannot simply call `Complaint::find($request->input('id'))` I must have to cross check with this `complaint_id` column value to find the resource. I have been searching since yesterday but could not find any solution. How can I solve this problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: "_on an object of a Model_" You're actually not, the errors state that those are `Eloquent\Collection`, not a Model. Try replacing `->get()` with `->first()`

Comment: try my answer. It will work.

Comment: YEP IT'S WORKING !!!! THANKSS!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `$complaint` is a collection of output. So `save` didn't work for this if you change your code like `$complaint = Complaint::where('complaint_id', $request->input('id'))->first();` Then `save()` will work.

Answer (score 1):

just use first() instead of get()

`Complaint::where('complaint_id', $request->id)->first()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! I tried this solution! it's working!

Answer (score 1):

In your query

```
$complaint = Complaint::where('complaint_id', $request->input('id'))->get();
```

it returns `Associative Arrays`

But if you use

```
$complaint = Complaint::where('complaint_id', $request->input('id'))->first();
```

it returns `Indexed or Numeric Arrays`. Then you have to use `$complaint[0]->destroy($request->input('id'));` or `$complaint[1]->destroy($request->input('id'));` and so one

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! I tried this solution! it's working!